# go to end of function when if statement true

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, scope

I write code in c#, I want to when if statement true execute  {do something11} and when if

statement false execute  {do something22}, statement1and statement2, i do not need to

execute statement1 and statement2 when if statement true . I use break ibn if statement but

not true  , how can I do that?

```
static void one_time(int x)

{

  if (x<10)

     {do something11}  // when if true

  else

     {do something22}// when else true

  statement1   // when else true

  statement2  // when else true
 }
```

Comment: You should work on more meaningful variable names.

Comment: Well why not just make your `else` block include statement1 and statement2?

Comment: You can always `return;` if you want to exit out of a function early.

Comment: Is this not just as simple as putting statements 1 and 2 inside the else block?

Answer (score 5):

You have enclosed just one statement in `else` block. So your last two statements would execute regardless of `if` or `else` condition.

If you add curly braces, you can create a [block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664737%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that will be executed:

```
if (x < 10)
{
    // if true, this block will be executed
    do something11  
}
else
{
    // else this entire block will be executed 
    do something22
    statement1   
    statement2  
}
```